# How can I draw edges from node to the same node itself?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use tikz to draw a three nodes in a triangle, connected by arrows. I want to add a rounded edge from each node to *itself*, basically adding edges like
`\path[<->] (left) edge (left)` to the example below. However, it seems that it does not seem to work like this. Can anyone give me a hint on how to approach this/where to look?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0)node[left] (left){news media };
\draw(5,0)node[right] (right) {citizens};
\draw(60:5)node[above] (above){political actors};
\path[<->] (left) edge (right);
\path[<->] (left) edge (above);
\path[<->] (above) edge (right);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You mean something like the option `loop left`, described in [section 70.4 in the pgfmanual on page 748](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=748)?

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan! Exactly that! I just did not know where to look. If your comment were an answer, I'd accept it ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already stated in the comment below the question this can be achieved using the `loop` options described in [section 70.4 in the pgfmanual (v3.0.1a) on page 748](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=748). Applied to your given example it would be something like

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw(0,0)node[left] (left){news media };
        \draw(5,0)node[right] (right) {citizens};
        \draw(60:5)node[above] (above){political actors};
        \path[<->] (left)
            edge (right)
            edge [loop left] node {bla} ()
        ;
        \path[<->] (right)
            edge (above)
            edge [loop right] node {bli} ()
        ;
        \path[<->] (above)
            edge (left)
            edge [loop above] node {blub} ()
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives the following result

[image: image showing the result of above code]